# Validate beginning of input field with multiple values

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have a login form that users are constantly getting wrong.  We are working on better informing the users but we would also like to hint them in the correct direction as they type in the input field.

All IDs are 10 characters and they start one of 4 different ways:

- A00
- B00
- CTR
- VST

I would like to hint users if they don't start with one of those 4 options, likely by triggering a hidden element to reveal itself that reminds them what a username looks like.

Most of the jQuery I can figure out, the only part I can't is the actual matching. I'm not really sure how to write the RegEx to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

This will match a correct string

`^((A00)|(B00)|(CTR)|(VST)).*$`

In JavaScript

`if (txt.search(/^((A00)|(B00)|(CTR)|(VST)).*$/) !== -1) {...}`